# Big size JSON String to JSONObject not work

Tags: android, json

```
protected class saveBtnClickHandler implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           String jsonRest = loadJsonDataFromURL("http://thirddhaba.appspot.com/api/v1/circle/condensed/data/?circle_id=1");
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonRest);  

        } catch (JSONException e) {
              android.util.Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}

protected String loadJsonDataFromURL(String url){
     String jsonStr = null;
    try {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                 jsonStr = out.toString();

            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return jsonStr;
}
```

[image] 
Above code is working fine. But this JSON ([Link](http://thirddhaba.appspot.com/api/v1/circle/condensed/data/?circle_id=1))URL string is not convert into JSON Object. I think this is big String also add error screen shot.

Comment: Could you provide more information? The output of the logcat will be very usefull.

Comment: @AitorTheRed  now i attached screen shot please review

Comment: If the problem is size of string, you should consider using stream parsing JSON, eg. using http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test data is enclosed in an array based on the []. You need to parse it as a json array and not as a json object.

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonRest);
```

Comment: I forget to see this, Thanks boss.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonRest);
```

With

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonRest);
```

I checked the `JSON` at http://thirddhaba.appspot.com/api/v1/circle/condensed/data/?circle_id=1

in JSONLint and I noticed that it is JSONArray.

**EDIT: FYI**

[ ] is used for JSONArray

{ } is used for JSONObject.